# Testing spring cloud service to service calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, microservices

I'm wondering what is the best way to test service to service calls? Currently each service resides in a separate sub-module. e.g.

```
/project
    /cat-service //Location of CatController
    /dog-service //Location of DogController, CatClient
```

#### Cat Service

The `CatController` looks like this:

```
class CatController
{
    int callCounter = 0;

    public int getCallCounter() { return callCounter; }

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/catservice/simple")
    public Object callCat() {
        callCounter++;
        return "purrrrrr";
    }
}
```

#### Dog Service

The `DogController` looks like this:

```
class DogController
{
    @Autowired
    CatClient catClient;

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/dogservice/simple")
    public Object callDog()
    {
        //In here make a call to the catservice over the network.
        catClient.callCatService();
        return "Woof woof";
    }
}
```

The `CatClient` looks like this:

```
@FeignClient("cat")
public interface CatClient
{
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/catservice/simple")
    public Object callCatService();
}
```

In order to test calls from dog-service to cat-service I will include cat-service within the dog-service for testing:

```
// dog-service/build.gradle
testCompile project(path: ':cat-service')
```

Then within the test class:

```
@IntegrationTest
public class DogTest
{
    @Autowired
    CatController catController;

    @Autowired
    DogController dogController;

    @Test
    public void testDogController() 
    {
        //Could spy on the catController instead.
        int callCountStart = catController.getCallCounter();
        dogController.callDog();

        assertTrue (catController.getCallCounter() > callCountStart);
        // Could also verify the state of the spy
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Is there any serious flaws with this?

Comment: what are you trying to test?

Comment: In my case the expected behaviour is that the `dogservice` will notify the `catservice` everytime there is a call to `/dogservice/simple`.